# Star Wars fanfic where the Resistance poisons Rey

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, fan-fiction

I think the premise was that Rey joined up with Kylo (don’t remember why or how). The Resistance ended up poisoning Rey and the only way to save her was for Kylo to surrender himself to the Resistance. Rey then thinks he’s been killed.

Comment: This is quite terse at the moment so could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11922/58193) and [edit] in anything else you may remember? For example, do you remember where you read this? When did you read this?